# Create constraints between two subviews programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a contentview inside a scrollview along with some other views, and scrollview height will change based on contentview height, and the height of the contentview is decided by the height of its subviews.

I am adding two subviews to contentview programmatically.

```
childView1 = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200))

childView2 = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 210, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200))

contentView.addSubview(childView1)
contentView.addSubview(childView2)

// childView1 top should be equal to contentView top           
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// childView2 bottom should be equal to contentView bottom                       
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView2, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// childView1 leading should be equal to contentView leading 

let leadingConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView1, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// childView1 trailing should be equal to contentView trailing  

let trailingConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView1, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// childView2 leading should be equal to contentView leading                       

let leadingConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView2, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// childView2 trailing should be equal to contentView trailing  

let trailingConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView2, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// Vertical Space between two child views is 10             
let constraintTwoSubViews = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView1, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: childView2, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)


contentView.addConstraints([topConstraint , bottomConstraint , leadingConstraint1,trailingConstraint1 , leadingConstraint2 , trailingConstraint2 , constraintTwoSubViews])
```

The problem is that the contentView height is not growing as per the subviews.
Because of that my scroll views is not growing.

1. When I am adding second child view, I do not want to specify y = 210
   , I want its position to be calculated by space constraint between
   two child views, Is it possible?
2. How can I make content view height grow as per its subviews?

Comment: make sure to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false for both `childView1` and `childView2` like: `childView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do when I need a scrollable view:

1. I add a `scrollView` to the hierarchy and use autolayout to properly layout it, e.g., if it is supposed to cover the whole `view` of the `viewController`:

   ```
   scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
       scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
       scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
       scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
   ])
   ```
2. Then you need to add a `contentView` to the `scrollView` and provide a proper layout constraints for it, so if you want vertically scrollable `scrollView` in the example I started above, you need following autolayout constraints:

   ```
   contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       // horizontal anchors of contentView are constrained to scrollView superview
       // to prevent it from scrolling horizontally
       contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
       contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
       // but vertical anchors of contentView are constrained to
       // scrollView to allow scrolling
       contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
       contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
   ])
   ```

   Notice here that I constrained the `leftAnchor` and `rightAnchor` of the `contentView` to the `self.view` rather than to `scrollView` to make it of fixed width. However, top and bottom anchors are constrained to the scrollView, so they are expanded and scrollable when `contentView` needs more space.
3. Now you add to the `contentView` all the content that you want, and you lay it out using autolayout as if the `contentView` was a view with infinite height - `scrollView` will take care of presenting it whole by scrolling. In your case I think you can use `UIStackView` to lay out those two views. However, `CustomView`'s frames will be calculated using autolayout, so I don't think you can rely on setting the frames directly - therefore I use constraints to set their heights too (widths will be stretched by the stackView):

   ```
   let stack = UIStackView()
   stack.spacing = 10
   stack.distribution = .fill
   stack.alignment = .fill
   stack.axis = .vertical

   contentView.addSubview(stack)
   stack.addArrangedSubview(childView1)
   stack.addArrangedSubview(childView2)

   childView1.translatesAutoresizingMasks = false
   childView2.translatesAutoresizingMasks = false

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.topAnchor),
       contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.leadingAnchor),
       contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.trailingAnchor),
       contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stack.bottomAnchor),

       // setting their heights using constraints
       childView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
       childView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
       ])
   ```